# Expected value of random exponential sum

Tags: number-theory, expectation, exponential-sum

Let for $n\le X$, let $\varepsilon_n$ be either $-1$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ (where all the $\varepsilon_n$ are independent). What would be the expected value of $$\int_0^1 \left\lvert\sum_{n\le X} \varepsilon_n e(n\alpha)\right\rvert d\alpha?$$

Comment: you are asking for $E[\int_0^1 \left\lvert\sum_{n\le X} \varepsilon_n e(n\alpha)\right\rvert d\alpha]$ ?

Comment: What is $e(n\alpha)$ here? And what is $X$? A random variable or just some real number? Over what set is $n$ ranging?

Comment: $e(n\alpha) := e^{2\pi i n\alpha}$. $X$ is a fixed large positive integer, so the answer should be a function of $X$. And $n$ is ranging over all positive integers less than or equal to $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it seems to be quite hard to calculate the expectation exactly, it is not too hard to obtain the order of magnitude in terms of $X$, by using Khinchin's inequality, which states the following:

There exist positive functions $A(p),B(p)$ such that whenever
 $a_1,\dots,a_m$ are complex numbers, one has, for $p>0$:

$$A(p)\left(\sum_{n=1}^m|a_n|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq\left(\mathbb{E}\left|\sum_{n=1}^ma_n\varepsilon_n\right|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq B(p)\left(\sum_{n=1}^m|a_n|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

In particular, for $p=1$:
$$\mathbb{E}\int_0^1\left|\sum_{n\leq m}\varepsilon_ne^{2\pi i n\alpha}\right|\,d\alpha\approx\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n\leq m}|e^{2\pi i n\alpha}|^2\right)^{1/2}\,d\alpha=\sqrt{m}$$
Since it is known that $A(1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, B(1)=1$, you can say that

> The expected value is between $\sqrt{\frac{X}{2}}$ and $\sqrt{X}$.

Comment: Can't we use that for $m$ large, $X(k) = \sum_{n \le m} \varepsilon_n e^{2i \pi nk/m}$ follows approximately a Gaussian distribution of zero mean, variance $m$ and zero covariance ?

Comment: Yes, perhaps we can, but the result is a lot less accurate or general.